# Grouping and Sum Linq to Entities

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following SQL Query and I have tried to convert it to LINQ but without any success:

```
select 
at.financialaccountid,
SUM(creditamount)-SUM(debitamount)
from account_transactions at
where at.financialaccountid = 47
and ledgervisible = 1
GROUP BY at.financialaccountid
```

[image: Result of Query]

Hope someone can guide me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should be a comparable C# LINQ implementation:

```
class AccountTransaction
{
    public int FinancialAccountId { get; set; }
    public bool LedgerVisible { get; set; }
    public decimal CreditAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal DebitAmount { get; set; }
}

var transactions = new List<AccountTransaction>();

var results = from at in transactions
              where at.FinancialAccountId == 4 && at.LedgerVisible == true
              group at by at.FinancialAccountId into g
              select new
              {
                  FinancialAccountId = g.Key,
                  Delta = g.Sum(x => x.CreditAmount) - g.Sum(x => x.DebitAmount)
              };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query =
    from at in account_transactions
    where at.financialaccountid == 47
    && at.ledgervisible == 1
    group at.financialaccountid into g
    select new
    {
        financialaccountid = g.Key,
        balance = g.Sum(at => at.creditamount) - g.Sum(at => at.debitamount)
    };
```